# Plotting images over a graph in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Does anyone know how can one plot() a regular 2D plot in Matlab,
and draw little images over that plot?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm, my bad, it's all there in the basic Matlab commands:

You do your plot(),
call 'hold on',
and then call 'image(x,y,img)' to plot that image on top of the existing plot.

:)